# Adding logstash "logstash-output-email" failed and restarting logstash failed to start

Tags: rubygems, logstash, gem-bundler

I tried to install "logstash-output-email" using below command and it could not installed due to firewall and then I came to know that there is a restriction that I can not use internet connectivity.

> ./logstash-plugin install logstash-output-email

Then I restarted the logstash and it started spawning new process ids every 5-10 secs and in the logs, it is looking for gem 'logstash-output-email'. Why is logstash not working when plugin installation has failed and installing the plugin has nothing to do with stating/stopping the logstash application.

I did verified what files has changed in the logstash install folder. One file has been created in the root install folder.

The error from the /var/log/logstash-stderr.log file:

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'logstash-output-email (>= 0) java' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
 verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found! at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:328
 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
 verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found! at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:307
 start at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:199
 resolve at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182
 resolve at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192
 specs at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132
 specs_for at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177
 requested_specs at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166
 requested_specs at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18
 setup at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13
 setup at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:122
 setup! at /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:64
 (root) at /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:64

Gemfile:

```
 This is a Logstash generated Gemfile.
# If you modify this file manually all comments and formatting will be lost.

source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "logstash-core", :path => "./logstash-core"
gem "logstash-core-event-java", :path => "./logstash-core-event-java"
gem "logstash-core-plugin-api", :path => "./logstash-core-plugin-api"
gem "file-dependencies", "0.1.6"
gem "ci_reporter_rspec", "1.0.0", :group => :development
gem "simplecov", :group => :development
gem "tins", "1.6", :group => :development
gem "rspec", "~> 3.1.0", :group => :development
gem "logstash-devutils", "~> 1.1", :group => :development
gem "benchmark-ips", :group => :development
gem "octokit", "3.8.0", :group => :build
gem "stud", "~> 0.0.22", :group => :build
gem "fpm", "~> 1.3.3", :group => :build
gem "rubyzip", "~> 1.1.7", :group => :build
gem "gems", "~> 0.8.3", :group => :build
gem "rack-test", :require => "rack/test", :group => :development
gem "flores", "~> 0.0.6", :group => :development
gem "term-ansicolor", "~> 1.3.2", :group => :development
gem "docker-api", "1.31.0", :group => :development
gem "pleaserun"
gem "logstash-input-heartbeat"
gem "logstash-codec-collectd"
gem "logstash-output-xmpp"
gem "logstash-codec-dots"
gem "logstash-codec-edn"
gem "logstash-codec-edn_lines"
gem "logstash-codec-fluent"
gem "logstash-codec-es_bulk"
gem "logstash-codec-graphite"
gem "logstash-codec-json"
gem "logstash-codec-json_lines"
gem "logstash-codec-line"
gem "logstash-codec-msgpack"
gem "logstash-codec-multiline"
gem "logstash-codec-netflow"
gem "logstash-codec-plain"
gem "logstash-codec-rubydebug"
gem "logstash-filter-clone"
gem "logstash-filter-csv"
gem "logstash-filter-date"
gem "logstash-filter-dns"
gem "logstash-filter-drop"
gem "logstash-filter-fingerprint"
gem "logstash-filter-geoip"
gem "logstash-filter-grok"
gem "logstash-filter-json"
gem "logstash-filter-kv"
gem "logstash-filter-metrics"
gem "logstash-filter-mutate"
gem "logstash-filter-ruby"
gem "logstash-filter-sleep"
gem "logstash-filter-split"
gem "logstash-filter-syslog_pri"
gem "logstash-filter-throttle"
gem "logstash-filter-urldecode"
gem "logstash-filter-useragent"
gem "logstash-filter-uuid"
gem "logstash-filter-xml"
gem "logstash-input-couchdb_changes"
gem "logstash-input-elasticsearch"
gem "logstash-input-exec"
gem "logstash-input-file"
gem "logstash-input-ganglia"
gem "logstash-input-gelf"
gem "logstash-input-generator"
gem "logstash-input-graphite"
gem "logstash-input-http"
gem "logstash-input-http_poller"
gem "logstash-input-imap"
gem "logstash-input-irc"
gem "logstash-input-jdbc"
gem "logstash-input-log4j"
gem "logstash-input-lumberjack"
gem "logstash-input-pipe"
gem "logstash-input-rabbitmq"
gem "logstash-input-redis"
gem "logstash-input-s3"
gem "logstash-input-snmptrap"
gem "logstash-input-sqs"
gem "logstash-input-stdin"
gem "logstash-input-syslog"
gem "logstash-input-tcp"
gem "logstash-input-twitter"
gem "logstash-input-udp"
gem "logstash-input-unix"
gem "logstash-input-xmpp"
gem "logstash-input-kafka", "< 6.0.0"
gem "logstash-input-beats"
gem "logstash-output-cloudwatch"
gem "logstash-output-csv"
gem "logstash-output-elasticsearch", "~> 5.2.1"
gem "logstash-output-file"
gem "logstash-output-graphite"
gem "logstash-output-http"
gem "logstash-output-irc"
gem "logstash-output-kafka", "< 6.0.0"
gem "logstash-output-nagios"
gem "logstash-output-null"
gem "logstash-output-pagerduty"
gem "logstash-output-pipe"
gem "logstash-output-rabbitmq"
gem "logstash-output-redis"
gem "logstash-output-s3"
gem "logstash-output-sns"
gem "logstash-output-sqs"
gem "logstash-output-statsd"
gem "logstash-output-stdout"
gem "logstash-output-tcp"
gem "logstash-output-udp"
gem "logstash-output-webhdfs"
gem "logstash-output-email"
```

Is it possible to edit the Gemfile to remove the last line manually and start the logstash. All I need is to start the logstash functioning so that I can do the debugging latter to install the logstash-output-email plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first trying to remove it:

```
sudo ./logstash-plugin remove logstash-output-email
```

When your behind a firewall, installation should be done via offline-plugins. See:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html

You need to prepare the offline-pack in a machine with full internet access, and then you can install behind a firewall, or without internet connection.

Comment: Imma @ Initially, I even tried to remove it and it has not removed. It was showing some gem error which I do not have now since I tried last week. so, I did removed the last line gem "logstash-output-email" and started the services. It worked.